# BIRT PDF UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, birt

I have some trouble with **BIRT** 4.3.1, I want to create some PDF with **BIRT**. This works all fine, but I have some problems with the encoding of my font.

For my font I am using Arial Narrow. This isn't a standard font which BIRT support. So I know that I must edit the fontsConfig_pdf.xml file in the JAR org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.3.1.v20130918-1142.jar file. Here look at my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<font>
    <composite-font name="all-fonts" font-family="Arial Narrow">
    </composite-font>
    <!-- define used Fonts -->
    <font-paths>
        <path path="/etc/fonts/ARIALN.TTF" />
    </font-paths>

    <!-- Encoding -->
    <font-encodings>
        <encoding font-family="Arial Narrow" encoding="UTF-8" />
    </font-encodings>     
</font>
```

I have put my font TTF file inside the location. All works fine, but the encoding is wrong for special signs.

Some hint to you, the encoding works well in my Windows-Machine but on my Linux-System it doesn't work. Maybe someone could give me a tip.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment in the default `fontsConfig.xml` file says, usually you don't have to add an entry to the `<font-encodings>` element at all.
However, for Linux and the Tahoma font (which I think is comparable to your case), I had to add

```
 <encoding font-family="Tahoma" encoding="Cp1252" />
```

AFAIK the encoding attribute tells BIRT how the glyphs are mapped to numbers inside the font file, I think. So UTF-8 definitely cannot be correct.
I guess that on Windows it works anyway because the encoding attribute isn't considered.

Comment: I have use the same instruction you supplied me before.
<font-encodings>
        <encoding font-family="Arial Narrow" encoding="Cp1252" />
</font-encodings>  
But I don't get the right format I wish, did you know how to add UTF-8 support for linux.

Comment: BTW are you sure that it is a font problem? I mean, itcould be some NLS issue AS well. You could check this by generating the report AS HTML.

Comment: And have you checked that your fontsConfig.xml file is processed by BIRT at all?

Comment: Two Comment for you:
I have try to generate a HTML Report, this works as I wish. Can you please explain me the meaning of NLS. My fontsConfig.xml must be processed by BIRT, if I leave the defaults values, I am getting not the correct at all.

Comment: If HTML is working this means that the data read from the DB is OK. I'm out of ideas, then...

Comment: Today I have the same problem while trying to display a Less-Or-Equal symbol U+2264 in a PDF. I made the following observations with a test report: If BIRT runtime is on Windows, everything works as expected. If BIRT runtime is on Linux, then only Dynamic Text (HTML) is rendered correctly - showing the text as a Data item ignores the <= symbol - even if I copy ARIALUNI.TTF into one of folders where BIRT is searching for fonts.